# how to install AMP on centos 5.5

Tags: linux, drupal, centos, lamp

i want to install Apache PHP MYSQL PhpMyAdmin Drupal in centos 5.5

i want to install last version of software
I do not know Linux Professional i know a little of base Linux

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to be a jerk, but [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/quick-n-easy-lamp-server-centos-rhel) was * literally* the [first result on google](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=lamp%20on%20centos).

The main bits:

```
#install Apache
yum install httpd httpd-devel
/etc/init.d/httpd start

#install MySQL
yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-devel
/etc/init.d/mysqld start

#set MySQL pass
mysql
```

Here, "mysql>" means you're in the MySQL prompt.

```
mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpassword') WHERE user='root';
mysql>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Check to make sure that your password works:

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter Password: <your new password>
```

Install PHP:

```
yum install php php-mysql php-common php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-devel php-xml
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Create a file named `/var/www/html/test.php` with the following:

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

You may want to install [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php):

```
yum install phpmyadmin
```

Comment: i know , i search in google but when use this command install php 5.1 and mysql 5.0.1 and ... i want install last version

Comment: You're not going to get the latest version from the base repositories.  If you want those, you're going to have to add a third-party repo.  [here's one for PHP](http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/), and [here's MySQL](http://www.webtatic.com/packages/mysql55/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the latest STABLE version of php and mysql.
You must install first the packages and update them.
You can use groupinstall under yum command.

MySQL

```
#check the packages under MySQL group
yum groupinfo "MySQL Database"

#you will see the list of mandatory, default and optional packages
#install the group package
yum groupinstall "MySQL Database"

#after install, check installed packages
rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
```

For PHP

```
#check the packages under Web Server group
yum groupinfo "Web Server"

#install the group package
yum groupinstall "Web Server"
```

You can also install the additional/optional packages such as php-mysql. etc.

```
yum install php-mysql
```

Now, time to update the installed packages. I found this repository thru the net and it's quite reliable.

Update PHP and MySQL

```
#update remi and rpm
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm

#update PHP and MySQL
yum --enablerepo=remi update php-\*
yum --enablerepo=remi update mysql-\*

#start the service
service httpd start
service mysqld start

#check the versions
php -v
mysql -v
```

Hope that helps.